# Connect a local spark cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark

I'm trying to connect a local spark cluster but I'm not succeeding.

I used the code:

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local",
spark_home="./spark/build/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3")

The first time it gave an error and R asked to install Java, I followed the guidance. Then I tried to run the code above again and the following error appeared:

Error in system2(file.path(spark_home, "bin", "spark-submit"), "--version",  :
'"./spark/build/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit"' not found

I tried to research to try to understand, but honestly I couldn't. Could you help me please? haha